# How to fix ' ImportError: cannot import name 'numpy_type_map' ' in Python?

Tags: python, pytorch, object-detection

I've followed the instructions in [Detectron](https://github.com/roytseng-tw/Detectron.pytorch) and I've configured it several times: the code compiles as it should. When it comes to run the code, I get this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "tools/train_net_step.py", line 21, in <module>
    import nn as mynn
    File "/home/federico/PycharmProjects/Detectron.pytorch/lib/nn/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .parallel import DataParallel
    File "/home/federico/PycharmProjects/Detectron.pytorch/lib/nn/parallel/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .data_parallel import DataParallel, data_parallel
    File "/home/federico/PycharmProjects/Detectron.pytorch/lib/nn/parallel/data_parallel.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .scatter_gather import scatter_kwargs, gather
    File "/home/federico/PycharmProjects/Detectron.pytorch/lib/nn/parallel/scatter_gather.py", line 8, in <module>
    from torch.utils.data.dataloader import numpy_type_map
    ImportError: cannot import name 'numpy_type_map'
```

I've also tried to google it many times, but I can't find a way to solve it. What can I do? I'm using PyTorch 0.4.1 and pytorch nightly 1.0.0-dev.

EDIT: Thanks to sancelot, I managed to solve that error (PyTorch 0.4.0 did the thing). Anyway, now I've got another error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "tools/train_net_step.py", line 27, in <module>
    from modeling.model_builder import Generalized_RCNN
    File "/home/federico/PycharmProjects/Detectron.pytorch/lib/modeling/model_builder.py", line 11, in <module>
    from model.roi_pooling.functions.roi_pool import RoIPoolFunction
    File "/home/federico/PycharmProjects/Detectron.pytorch/lib/model/roi_pooling/functions/roi_pool.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .._ext import roi_pooling
    File "/home/federico/PycharmProjects/Detectron.pytorch/lib/model/roi_pooling/_ext/roi_pooling/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from ._roi_pooling import lib as _lib, ffi as _ffi
    ImportError: /home/federico/PycharmProjects/Detectron.pytorch/lib/model/roi_pooling/_ext/roi_pooling/_roi_pooling.so: undefined symbol: PyInt_FromLong
```

What I can't get this time is: is this an error given by an external library? I'm using an anaconda environment previously made by my professor, who has used it for Detectron... so I can't guess why I get this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose there is a version mismatch between detectron and the needed pytorch release you are using.
if you look at latest pytorch source code, there is no numpy_type_map component.
https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py

Comment: Ok, I'll try to downgrade it and let you know, thanks for now.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, these are due to Pytorch version mismatch. Solution depends on what extent you are willing to go, sometimes if you are okay with hacking and just getting it running, then just copy paste the `numpy_type_map` from older versions:

```
numpy_type_map = {
     'float64': torch.DoubleTensor,
     'float32': torch.FloatTensor,
     'float16': torch.HalfTensor,
     'int64': torch.LongTensor,
     'int32': torch.IntTensor,
     'int16': torch.ShortTensor,
     'int8': torch.CharTensor,
     'uint8': torch.ByteTensor,
 }
```

Or, up to version 1.1.0, you can try replacing the import statement,

**from**:

```
from torch.utils.data.dataloader import numpy_type_map
```

**to**:

```
from torch.utils.data._utils.collate import numpy_type_map
```

N.b. will still break in more recent versions. Again, this is a *hacky* **quick-fix** solution.